# Node js, http request, error on parse result

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Fetching data from an external api:

```
var request = http.get('http:...format=json', function(resFromApi) {
  if(resFromApi.statusCode !== 200){
    res.status(400).send(data);
    return;
  }
  resFromApi.on('data', function(data) {
    var test = JSON.parse(data);
    res.status(200).send(data); 
  });
});
request.end();
```

I'm using a rest api to use this service. If I run it in my browser the result is returned as a file, with the json data in it. If I try to run `JSON.parse(data)`, the console gives:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token i
    at Object.parse (native)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/Library/WebServer/Documents/VF/node/server.js:58:25)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:764:14)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:426:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:422:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody [as onBody] (http.js:142:22)
```

If I copy paste the api-url directly in my browser, json data is show as expected.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: you cannot send any data with a get request, you need to parse the complete response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` event will return *chunked* data which more often than not, depending on the data vs buffer size, contains only part of the complete response (hence the reason for `JSON.parse` throwing a wobbly).

In your case though, the `JSON.parse` call seems redundant as you are just trying copying data from one request to another. With that being the case, you can simply [pipe](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) the data into the destination stream

```
resFromApi.pipe(res);
```